# SerialPort.ReadLine() returns garbage

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I am reading data from a scale using a serial port.  Communication is working fine, but I'm getting garbage from the serial port.

An example:

```
???s.R?????0?   ??o???????0?    ??o???????0?
```

My problem is, I don't know the behavior of the scale. I don't know if its sending me hex, binary or what.  And I don't know what value its actually sending.  I don't have any documentation on the scale to research it.

So I guess, by default, what is normally sent back over the serial port and how do I convert it into a readable value?

Comment: Do you not have documentation for the scale or the drivers for it?  The data could be almost anything...

Comment: Write what kind of scales you have? If you don't have documentation it doesn't mean that you cant find it on internet or send a request for manufacturers.

Comment: The scale is a custom made job. Some versions use Modbus inside, but this one doesn't. The scales are used at meat processing plants to weigh cuts of meat. There are no drivers for it and no documentation for it.

Comment: How are you displaying the data you received from the serial port?  Looks like you're converting to a string.

Comment: I'm new to the Serial Port world, so I may not be doing it right.  On the DataReceived event handler, I do: string data = port.ReadExisting();

Comment: And my port declaration: SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM9", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);

Comment: Have you tried using the Read() instead of ReadLine()?  Since ReadLine() is returning a string, it is more than likely altering the data during the conversion to a string.  I am not overly familiar with the SerialPort class, but it appears that you could call read and us the BytesToRead property to know how many byte to read to your buffer.  From there, you could dump the contents to a file and analyze it in a hex editor to see if you can make sense of it.  Without the documentation, I'm not sure how useful that will be, but its a start.

Comment: even simply using `var data = port.ReadExisting();` and then looking at data in the watch window may be instructive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That many question marks is a sign of having the SerialPort settings wrong.  Starting with Baudrate, Parity is next.

If the scale sends binary data then the Encoding property matters.  The default is ASCII so that generates a lot of question marks if the bytes in the binary data are >= 128.  In which case you should use Read() instead of ReadLine().  Which is what you want to use to start to troubleshoot this problem, you want to look at the raw byte values, you can't see much from question marks.  Pay extra attention to the last one or two bytes you get from a reading, they should repeat well.

Comment: I played with the settings, and now I'm getting some consistent data. Figured out the scale is sending Hex, now I just have to figure out what its sending. Thanks!

Comment: Actually what you want to use to start to troubleshoot this kind of problem is a serial port monitor program. There are several free or cheap ones available.