# serialprot readline() adding questionmark "?"

Tags: c#, serial-port, readline

I want read from serialport line of text by readline()
text is ASCII and in terminal is all OK (data are realy good), but when I read by readline, it returns somewhere in text ?
example - this is regular :

```
!!!;34;248;45;215;43;226;33;235;32;240;35;250;36;240;37;246;40;263;41;272;42;261;39;270;44;256;47;241;49;8888;50;8888;38;245;46;460;48;363
```

This returns readline() :

```
!!!;34;248;45;215;43;226;?33;235;32;240;35;250;36;240?;37;246;40;263;41;272;42;261?;39;270;44;256;47;241;49;888?8;50;8888;38;245;46;460;48;3?63
```

Code is simple:

```
this.serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";    
this.serialPort1.BaudRate = 19200;                     
this.serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.Mark; 
this.serialPort1.Open();

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    prectenyRadek=this.serialPort1.ReadLine();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
}

private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(prectenyRadek);    
}
```

Has anybody have idea, what and why add me "?"

Comment: on serial there are really ASCII data like this:0D 0A 21 21 21 3B 33 34 3B 32 34 38 3B 34 35 3B 32 31 35 3B 34 33 3B 32 32 36 3B 33 33 3B 32 33 35 3B 33 32 3B 32 34 30 3B 33 35 3B 32 35 30 3B 33 36 3B 32 34 30 3B 33 37 3B 32 34 36 3B 34 30 3B 32 36 33 3B 34 31 3B 32 37 32 3B 34 32 3B 32 36 31 3B 33 39 3B 32 37 30 3B 34 34 3B 32 35 36 3B 34 37 3B 32 34 31 3B 34 39 3B 38 38 38 38 3B 35 30 3B 38 38 38 38 3B 33 38 3B 32 34 35 3B 34 36 3B 34 35 37 3B 34 38 3B 33 36 32 3B 0D 0A   (first 0D 0A is EOL line before and follow what You see in HEX and finish 0D 0A too)

Answer (score 1):

"If the scale sends binary data then the Encoding property matters. The default is ASCII so that generates a lot of question marks if the bytes in the binary data are >= 128. In which case you should use Read() instead of ReadLine(). Which is what you want to use to start to troubleshoot this problem, you want to look at the raw byte values, you can't see much from question marks. Pay extra attention to the last one or two bytes you get from a reading, they should repeat well."

Source: [SerialPort.ReadLine() returns garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653211/serialport-readline-returns-garbage)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was the parity. It started work fine,when i switched parity from Mark to Space.  (data between my line are parity Mark, but this line havenot somewhere 9 bit).