# c# read serial in hex

Tags: c#, serial-port, windows-forms-designer

I am using the SDS011 laser dust sensor and want to read the data in a Windows forms Application.
I get Hex Data. Example: AA C0 D4 04 3A 0A A1 60 1D AB
now the fourth and the third pair represent the PM2.5 value, in this example: 04D4 -> 1236 -> 123,6 ug/m^3
Could you please help me write a code for reading in the hex data and calculating the PM2.5 value?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is coming as a string then it's simple as:

```
string inputData = "AA C0 D4 04 3A 0A A1 60 1D AB";
var inputDataSplit = inputData.Split(' ');
// Concatenate the fourth and the third string, and convert it to integer with base 16 (hex)
int pmValue = Convert.ToInt32(inputDataSplit[3] + inputDataSplit[2], 16);
        
// 1236
Console.Write(pmValue);
```

Comment: and do you maybe have an idea how to read the input, because I am reading the input with Serial.ReadLine(); and when I output the value it is showing weird signs, I think this is because the console is printing the ascii letters referring to that hex input. And the input ist without spaces, can I also somehow add them(AAC0D4043A0AA1601DAB to AA C0 D4 04 3A 0A A1 60 1D AB)?

Comment: The input read garbage is probably because you are not reading the bytes as they are expected. Here's more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653211/serialport-readline-returns-garbage

Comment: You can either pad the string with spaces if you are reading them in an interval of 1 byte, append them using a StringBuilder, then append space, then the next one and so on... Alternatively if the byte string does not have spaces, you can achieve the same using string.Substring() function. You can read the substring starting from position 6 with length 2, and then the substring starting from position 4 length 2 and concatenate them.